# Qt designer: Custom code for custom actions

Tags: python, pyqt, designer, signals-slots

I've been looking around and I didn't found anything yet, except old doc for Qt3 with version 3.x of qt designer.

I'll leave an example, not that I can't give code as my project is GPL but for simplicity.

***Example:*** You are designing a GUI for your application. You insert some buttons in the GUI, and you want those buttons do something with a logic that *maybe* is already written.

***Question:*** How do you add or set this code in a way that the button when it's checked will fire that code?

I don't want to connect widgets with signals/slots. My approach was to create a custom action in the action editor, and connect the desired button to that action hoping to find a way to write the code for that action. I could define its name, its icon (?), and so on. But I need to write its logic/code.

I read some [documentation](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~afedosov/qttut/) that instructs you to create a C++ header file, but it seems deprecated for the new Qt Designer version  (4.7.3). The other vast resource I found about my question are all about conecting signals between default objetc actions. I repeat that is not what I need/want.

My question born from the fact that I don't want to edit the generated .py. I sense that it MUST be a way to set a file (custom code, header file, etc) with the custom action code but honestly, I can't find anything yet.

In case of a negative answer (that is, "not possible to do so"), It would be nice to hear some advice for "hacking" the code. I really don't like to modify the generated .py and it seems ugly to do something like: `ui.callback` in my code.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to create a header file or modify the `pyuic` generated file. Assuming your action object is named `myaction` and you want to signal `myaction_slot` when it's toggled:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

# import pyuic generated user interface file
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # connect myaction_logic to myaction.toggled signal
        self.myaction.toggled.connect(self.myaction_slot)

    def myaction_slot(self):
        pass # do something here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyMainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That was easier than I expected, did I miss something in the Qt docs? Thanks btw for your effort and clear code.

Comment: @Sebastian Maybe? I found it very confusing when I started as well. I usually use PySide, their documentation/tutorials were what I read when I started working with Qt (PySide/PyQt are more or less interchangeable): http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Newbie_Tutorials

Comment: I removed my previous comment, sry, I've commented something pretty wrong. Thanks, again.

Comment: And what if you want to use a custom widget? What is the best practice considering that I want to still using Qt designer?